# Django's list_select_related does not show foreign key's attributes

Tags: django, django-admin

Basically I am trying to have the attributes of a foreign key available both in the list_display and in the admin editor. However, even using the list_select_related (I have also tried modifying the queryset with the select_related method) the foreign key attributes do not appear in any of the mentioned admin screens. Toy example:

```
class BookAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_select_related = ('author',)
```

Where the book model has a OneToOne relationship with author, and author has some attributes (first_name, last_name, etc.) that I want to display in the admin site. Am I forgetting something? I know I could do lookups to list and inlines to edit, but it doesn't seem like a very optimal solution ...

Thank you very much!

Comment: list_select_related is just there for optimization as documented https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related

Comment: Oh, I understand then that the idea of using the list_select_related would be to keep the lookups, but optimizing the queries?

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case I think you are looking to use the following Admin class properties:

- list_display [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display): Using your example, if you want to display the name of the book and its author name in the admin:

```
class BookAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('name', 'author',)
```

- search_fields [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) Now if you also want to be able to filter by book name as well as their author names:

```
class BookAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('name', 'author',)
     list_filter = ['name', 'author__name']
```